# input stream read is always empty

Tags: java, inputstream

I'm trying to get an image from a URL and add the image to a zipfile. When I try to read from the stream (`read(buf)) > 0`), the condition is always false. I'm not understanding what I'm missing. Any ideas?

```
File tempZipFile = File.createTempFile("zip_images", ".zip");
ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tempZipFile));
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
String imageUrl = "";
```

Attempt 1:

```
InputStream is;
is = new URL(imageUrl).openStream();
zipStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("my_image.jpg"));
int len;
while ((len = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
    zipStream.write(buf, 0, len);
}
```

Attempt 2:

```
URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
zipStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("my_image.jpg"));
int len;
while ((len = urlStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
    zipStream.write(buf, 0, len);
}
```

Attempt 3:

```
URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
InputStream is = url.openStream();
zipStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("my_image.jpg"));
int len;

while ((len = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
    os.write(b, 0, len);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `read` can return 0 in some cases when there are no bytes immediately available, and yet return a positive number on subsequent calls. The first thing I would check is, are you actually getting data from the input stream. Also, if you are using at least Java 9 or later it might be better and easier to use `is.transferTo(zipStream)`.

Comment: I see that outputStream is null.

Comment: The `zipStream` is `null`? Maybe you should just try using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` for now, until you get the read working.

Comment: I replicated Attempt 1 code and it works for me. Check your image url.

Comment: @DavidConrad it can't. `read` will block until it can read at least 1 byte. It doesn't necessarily fill all space available, but it will fill at least 1 byte. If it can't, it'll wait. If the stream ends, it returns -1. I think the only way to get `0` out, is to call `byte[] b = new byte[0]; in.read(b)`, which academic (pointless).

Comment: The issue was the URL.